# Why a conformal operator of world sheet spin $n$ had $n$ index $O^{\mu_1\mu_2...\mu_n}$

Tags: coordinate-systems, quantum-spin, tensor-calculus, conformal-field-theory

Consider a conformal operator of world sheet spin $n$, for example, $h=a,\bar h=b$ and $s=|a-b|$ then the operator would be labeled by $n$ index, $\mu_1,\mu_2,...,\mu_n$, where each index of dimension $d$.

I thought this might has something to do with the verma module, where at each different level, i.e. $1,2,...,a$ was an independent vector space, but then it should be $a+b$ instead of $|a-b|$, and the existence of the null vectors also made less sense for the vector space, since spin was a general definition.

Why a conformal operator of world sheet spin $n$ had $n$ index $O^{\mu_1\mu_2...\mu_n}$?

Comment: How does $O^{\mu_1 \cdots \mu_n}$ transform under conformal transformations and how do the spin $n$ fields transform?

Comment: @Prahar Under conformal transformation $z\rightarrow w$ it transformed as $\prod_i (\frac{\partial w_i}{\partial z_i})^{h_i} (\frac{\partial \bar w_i}{\partial \bar z_i})^{\bar h_i}   $. For spin $n$ fields, the conformal transformation worked the same.

Comment: yes, I know. now work out how $O$ transforms under the same transformation. Is it the exact same transformation?

Comment: @Prahar I haven't dealt with higher spin before except $T^{\mu\nu}$ and I thought that was the definition of the conformal invariance of the conformal field theory. However, looking at the Wikipedia the $\langle O_{\mu_1...\mu_l}(x_1)O_{\nu_1...\nu_l}(x_2)\rangle$ does have an extra $\prod_i I_{\mu_i\nu_i}(x_1-x_2)-traces$ in the numerator which was rather confusing. There an additional $\prod_i \frac{w_{\mu_i} w_{\nu_i}}{w_i^2} \cdot \frac{z_i^2}{z_{\mu_i} z_{\nu_i}}\sim \prod_i(\frac{w_i}{z_i} \cdot ... )^2 $ where $w_\mu=(w_1-w_2)_\mu$,  $z_\mu=(z_1-z_2)_\mu$.

Comment: I suggest reading https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.04074

Comment: @Vicky (which equation?)I encountered it before it's mostly like Ginsparg's or the yellow book, the expression were focused on scalar fields without the spin index such as their section 3.

Comment: If you want transformations of tensor you'd need to read Ferrara at al.'s papers, e.g. https://inspirehep.net/literature/77568. I sent you the review by Qualls because if you don't understand why the VEV of the product of two conformal tensors goes with $\prod_{i}I_{\mu_i\nu_i} - traces$, it means you are lacking fundaments of CFT. For that read Qualls as well as papers by Ferrara, Parisi, Grillo and Gato in CFT

Comment: @Vicky It doesn't matter what the understanding of VEV or not, or shadow formalism(I never bothered to read it since I don't need to learn everything to start work on something). The vacuum was assumed stable and invariant in most of CFTs thus often not mentioned. The conformal invariance of the fields were often given as \textbf{definition}, that was fundamental. That's the part confused me because obviously with the spin the transformation did not seem to be quite conformal as it seemed. Also, none of those explained why the spin became the number of operator index. Your links didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $d$ dimensions, the conformal group is $SO(d,2)$. A conformal primary operator with scaling dimension $\Delta$ and which lives in a representation $D$ of $SO(d)$ transforms (under conformal transformations) as
$$
O(x) \to \Omega_g(x)^\Delta D(R_g(x)^{-1}) \cdot O(x_g(x))
$$
where $\Omega_g(x)$ is the conformal factor corresponding to the conformal transformation $x_g^\mu(x)$ and
$$
R_g(x)^\mu{}_\nu = \Omega_g(x)^{-1} \frac{\partial x_g^\mu(x)}{\partial x^\nu} \in SO(d) . 
$$
Let us now apply this definition to the special case where the operator $O$ is a tensor operator, $O \equiv O_{\mu_1 \cdots \mu_s}$. In this case, the conformal transformation simplifies to
$$
O_{\mu_1\cdots\mu_s}(x) \to \Omega_g(x)^\Delta R_g(x)^{\nu_1}{}_{\mu_1}  \cdots R_g(x)^{\nu_s}{}_{\mu_s} O_{\nu_1 \cdots \nu_s}  (x_g(x))
$$
We now further simplify this to the special case of $d=2$. Working in complex coordinates, conformal transformations are $z \to f(z)$. In this case, $\Omega(z,{\bar z}) = |f'(z)|$ and $R(z,{\bar z})^z{}_z = |f'(z)|^{-1} f'(z)$ and $R(z,{\bar z})^z{}_{\bar z} = 0$. Since $R^z{}_{\bar z}=0$, we see that the $z$ component of a tensor does not mix with the ${\bar z}$ component under conformal transformation.

Consider now the "all-$z$" component of the tensor operator $O$. Under conformal transformations, this transforms as
\begin{align}
O_{z \cdots z}(z,{\bar z}) &\to |f'(z)|^\Delta \left[ |f'(z)|^{-1} f'(z) \right]^s O_{f \cdots f}  (f(z),{\bar f}({\bar z})) \\
&= f'(z)^{\frac{1}{2}(\Delta+s)} {\bar f}'({\bar z})^{\frac{1}{2}(\Delta-s)}  O_{f \cdots f}  (f(z),{\bar f}({\bar z}))
\end{align}
We now set
$$
h = \frac{1}{2} ( \Delta + s ) , \qquad {\tilde h} = \frac{1}{2} ( \Delta - s ) 
$$
and find
\begin{align}
O_{z \cdots z}(z,{\bar z}) &\to f'(z)^h {\bar f}'({\bar z})^{{\tilde h}}  O_{f \cdots f}  (f(z),{\bar f}({\bar z}))
\end{align}
This is precisely the transformation law for an operator with conformal weight $(h,{\tilde h})$

Comment: Thank you. Could you give some explanation or reference to $R_g(x)^\mu_{\nu}$ please? I assumed "the conformal factor " was the $\Omega_g(x)^{\Delta}= (|\frac{\partial x_g^\mu}{\partial x_\nu}| |...| )^{-\Delta/d}$(In Di Francesco that defined quasi primary in Eq. 4.32). But I don't understand why there's $D(R_g(x)^{-1})$ appear.

Comment: For example, the covariant tensor transformation for each sub index contributed to the $\frac{\partial x_g^\mu(x)}{\partial x^\mu}$, but why there's $\Omega_g(x)^{-1}$ term associated with it? That's not in the definition of quasi primary, nor in the definition of tensor algebra. I suspected it came from $g_{\mu\nu}(x)\rightarrow g'_{\mu\nu}(x')=\Omega(x)_g g_{\mu\nu}(x)$ but there's extra terms.

Comment: (4.32) is for a spinless field as Di Francesco clearly mentions so in that case $D=1$. For more general spinning fields the formula I wrote is true. The extra $\Omega_g(x)^{-1}$ factor is related to the fact that you are doing a conformal transformation, not a diffeomorphism. To verify what I have written, you can check that the transformation I wrote down preserves the group multiplication law.